# Why does Hybris ship insecure http maven repository URL? And why can't we override it?

Tags: java, maven, sap-commerce-cloud

In `apache-ant/lib/libraries.properties`

> m2.repo=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

What is the point of shipping Hybris with `http` URL?
 It cannot be accessed in the first place, let alone used for downloading.
Ideally, it should be an `https` URL.

> m2.repo=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

I tried *overriding* it by redeclaring this property in `local.properties`. When that did not pick the new value, I changed it to `https` in `apache-ant/lib/libraries.properties`, but it is still picking `http`. How to override this property?

Error logs:

```
[artifact:mvn] Downloading: org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.2.5/apache-maven-3.2.5.pom from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
[artifact:mvn] Error transferring file: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
[artifact:mvn] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven:apache-maven:pom:3.2.5' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
     [null] An error has occurred while processing the Maven artifact tasks.
     [null]  Diagnosis:
     [null] 
     [null] Unable to resolve artifact: Missing:
     [null] ----------
     [null] 1) org.apache.maven:apache-maven:pom:3.2.5
     [null]   Path to dependency: 
     [null]     1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0
     [null]     2) org.apache.maven:apache-maven:pom:3.2.5
     [null] 
     [null] ----------
     [null] 1 required artifact is missing.
     [null] 
     [null] for artifact: 
     [null]   org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0
     [null] 
     [null] from the specified remote repositories:
     [null]   central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
     [null] 
     [null] 

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Great finding! +1 for posting it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can override this by setting up your $HOME/.m2/settings.xml file.

For example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>default</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

</settings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Redeclaring `m2.repo` in `local.properties` won't work as there is no such property loaded by Hybris. You can verify it by searching for `m2.repo` in  **hAC > Platform > Configuration** (or simply at https://localhost:9002/platform/config).

Modifying it in `apache-ant/lib/libraries.properties` should work if you execute `ant`. Please let me know if it is not the case and I will try to find some other option.

> When that did not pick the new value, I changed it to `https` in
>   `apache-ant/lib/libraries.properties`, but it is still picking `http`. How
>   to override this property?

It would be helpful if you mention where do you see it picking `http`. Please mention the steps to replicate this behavior.

Comment: great to hear from you sir....we worked together in Medtronics.....
I am getting the error as a last line in `ant clean all`.....when I set `usemaven=true` as one of the attributes.....

Comment: What a surprise! I saw your name a few times but couldn't recognize you because you haven't used your own picture at the DP. I hope you are doing well and I am sure you must be an asset to your team. I wish you a very successful career! Coming back to your problem, I was able to replicate the issue in my system when I updated the `external-dependendencies.xml` in a custom extension and changed `usemaven=true` in its `extensioninfo.xml`. Then, I tried the solution provided by `Neil Hubert-Price` and it worked. Please do accept his answer so that others can also use it confidently.

Comment: It has also been answered at https://answers.sap.com/questions/12957190/maven-central-repository-link-broken.html